# lambda cold start time increased with code size/Python imports

Tags: aws-lambda

I deployed a 'hello world' lambda function to AWS written in Python 3.6, and measured it's cold start initialization time with AWS X-Ray to be 2 milliseconds on first invocation.  I then added two more functions to the source code file, deployed it, and saw that the cold start initialization time for that same 'hello world' function was now 1.1 seconds.  The size of the package I uploaded had increased from 1.6 to 9.8 MB in size, due to the extra database libraries like sqlalchemy, etc; but even after increasing the memory allocation to 512 MB (from 128 MB) the time only decreased to 1.0 seconds.

None of the functions are deployed inside a VPC.

Could a few library imports done at the global level have added 1 second to the initialization time?

[Original code](https://pastebin.com/n5psPX6T) is like this:

```
def test():
    try:
        return wrapper('hello world', type='text')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e, exc_info=True)
```

Relevant imports from the [updated code](https://pastebin.com/) are:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Float, DateTime, Boolean, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, exists
from sqlalchemy.pool import Pool, NullPool

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sentry_sdk
from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray_recorder
from aws_xray_sdk.ext.sqlalchemy.query import XRaySessionMaker
```

Comment: Please post the whole original and updated code. As you're wondering what the issue could be, you might not be able to assess what the relevant parts of the code are.

Comment: Are you establishing a database connection when the Lambda function initializes?

Comment: @MarkB no - just doing the module imports

Comment: *"measured it's cold start initialization time with AWS X-Ray to be 2 milliseconds on first invocation"*  That suggests a flaw in your test methodology.  A 2 ms cold-start seems impossibly fast.

Answer (score 5):

After every invocation AWS print a report message that includes the "Init Duration" (Cold-start init time)
[image]
If there is no `Init Duration` in the report message, it means that the lambda was "warm" and it basically re-used the same container.

As a side note I can mention that package size **Do** effect the Init duration time, there are a few tools that help you measure the cold-start effect over time.

On Lumigo - we have a detailed blog-post here about cold-starts and a few tips and tricks on how to reduce the effect, and shows **how much** impact the package size had

https://lumigo.io/blog/this-is-all-you-need-to-know-about-lambda-cold-starts/

Answer (score 0):

That's not very likely, and your 2-millisecond initialization duration seems unrealistic. Does CloudWatch Log for your Lambda instance report that duration in the `Init Duration` field on the log item for an invocation to a newly initialized instance?

For more on this topic - the length of cold-starts - read this interesting post: https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/aws/. Average cold-start durations are between 300-800 ms.